# Behavior issues after one of three dogs dies

Tags: behavior, multi-pet-families

My question/ problem is; We got a rescue golden retriever when she was 9yrs old (CoCo) and a few weeks later we got a blue/red nose little girl pit named Tater who was 12 weeks. Tootsie (Rot/Doberman) female 6 months older then Tater joined the family. As soon as CoCo started to slow down a lot Tater got pushy and aggression with her and I read to stop that was to let CoCo be first and make Tater wait. This worked great. Now my problem is we just lost CoCo and Tater is upset looking for her and now she is fighting, being a bully to Tootsie to the point of us breaking up major fights.  Tootsie is more passive then Tater but will tease her and Tater is a bully. How or what can we try to get balance back. Tater is spayed but Tootsie is not.

Comment: I have reworded your title so it is more clear what the issue is, this should help you find an answer.  If you don't agree with the title change, please feel free to modify it.

Comment: How long has it been since CoCo passed?

Comment: Two weeks.:  ( . Now Tater and Tootsie won't eat.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a few years difference then need have the younger dog deffer to the older.  As during the final years of the older dog they just plain need it.  I start from the day the younger dog comes to the house.  The older dog gets to eat first.

In the case of the two about the same age you just let them work it out until one displays aggression the other does not handle.  At that point the more aggressive eats last.  But you may need more than just that in the situation you are in.  Discipline the more aggressive dog.  As soon as Tate begins to tease break it up and tell her no.

Comment: Thanks.. we lost CoCo two weeks ago. When Tater was born her mama was only 9 months old and she had 16 babies..Crazy but true. She didn't care for all of them and Tater happened to be one she pushed away so she didn't get taught manners.  CoCo was attacked by a pit so it took awhile for her to warm up to Tater.I will try your advice. Thsnks